# vglm in VGAM package for ordinal variables: what do the letters L and Q stand for?

Tags: r, vgam

I'm fitting a cumulative-logit model using an ordinal explicative, the coefficients I get are as following:

```
coefficients(cum_mod_podds_ord,matrix=TRUE)
             logit(P[Y>=2]) logit(P[Y>=3])
(Intercept)     -0.4106068     -1.2504301
depr_ord.L       1.3749694      1.3749694
depr_ord.Q      -0.1039784     -0.1039784
```

I'd like to know what the L and Q that the function put after the name of the variable stand for.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the contrasts for an ordered factor; contrasts based on orthogonal polynomials. The `L` is for the "linear" polynomial term , the `Q` for the quadratic term. This is a bit like `x` and `x^2` and so on, but just in terms of contrasts for the ordered factor.

If you have three levels in the ordered factor, the polynomial contrasts for those levels are:

```
> zapsmall(contr.poly(3))
             .L         .Q
[1,] -0.7071068  0.4082483
[2,]  0.0000000 -0.8164966
[3,]  0.7071068  0.4082483
```

where the rows above are the 3 levels of the factor. Each level in the factor is then replaced by the corresponding `.L` and `.Q` values (hence the factor is replaced by two variables in the model matrix).

If you need more info than this, Stackoverflow probably isn't the place; try [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) instead.